# How to download files stored in server and save to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ftp

In my server for every hour one file gets generated which is typically 250 to 300 mb
I want to download these files and place under hadoop.
If anybody got any ideas please reply how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Hadoop comes with powerful and useful set of commands line. Have a look at: [Hadoop FileSystem Shell](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html).
Particularly, `copyFromLocal` and `put` commands. With regular Shell commands, you can combine Hadoop command line with SSH if you want.

Comment: +1 put commands into a cron job if cron is available in your environment (task scheduler for Windows) so that the hadoop commands run in the time interval you need.